# JS: check if browser supports focus options

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

Is there any way to detect (without using `user-agent` and similar) that `.focus()` supports **focusOptions**, like: `preventScroll: true`.

I'm using this in Chrome:

```
element.focus({
  preventScroll: true
});
```

for sure, this won't work anywhere except Chrome and Opera.
But how can I detect this? Like:

```
try { window.focus().preventScroll } catch {...}
```

is it possible somehow?

Comment: I can think of a way, but it involves (possibly) scrolling and also could return false negatives due to user action, so...not helpful.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you explain it?

Comment: Ensure you have an input off the bottom of the viewport, issue the call, and see if the scroll position changed. If it did, the browser doesn't support `preventScroll` **or** the user happened to scroll. If it didn't, perhaps the browser supports it.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
    let supported = false;

    document.createElement('div').focus({
        get preventScroll() {
            supported = true;

            return false;
        },
    });

    console.log(supported);
```